# sinon stub fails for promise functions if not exported within class

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, module, export, stub

I'm trying to get sinon.stub to work for async function. I have created promiseFunction.js:

```
let functionToBeStubbed = async function() {
    return ("Text to be replaced by stub.");
};

let promiseFunction = async function() {
    return(await functionToBeStubbed());
};

module.exports = {
    promiseFunction: promiseFunction,
    functionToBeStubbed: functionToBeStubbed
};
```

and test promiseFunction.spec.js:

```
let functionstobestested = require('./promiseFunction.js');

describe('Sinon Stub Test', function () {
    var sandbox;

    it('should return --Text to be replaced by stub.--', async function () {    

        let responsevalue = "The replaced text.";
        sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
        sandbox.stub(functionstobestested, 'functionToBeStubbed').resolves(responsevalue);
        //sandbox.stub(functionstobestested, 'functionToBeStubbed').returns(responsevalue);

        let result = "Empty";
        console.log(`BEFORE: originaldata = ${result}, value = ${responsevalue}`);
        result = await functionstobestested.promiseFunction();
        console.log(`AFTER: originaldata = ${result}, value = ${responsevalue}`);
        expect(result).to.equal(responsevalue);

        sandbox.restore();
        console.log("AFTER2: Return value after restoring stub: " + await functionstobestested.promiseFunction());
    });
```

});

when running the test, I will get
[test failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4g6N.png)

If I modify export slightly, it still fails:

```js
var functionsForTesting = {
    promiseFunction: promiseFunction,
    functionToBeStubbed: functionToBeStubbed
};

module.exports = functionsForTesting;
```

I do not understand why this test fails, as it should pass. If I change the way I export functions from promiseFunction.js - module, the test pass correctly. Revised promiseFunction.js:

```js
const functionsForTesting = {
    functionToBeStubbed: async function() {
        return ("Text to be replaced by stub.");
    },

    promiseFunction: async function() {
        return(await functionsForTesting.functionToBeStubbed());
};

module.exports = functionsForTesting;
```

[Test pass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJKMm.png)

What's wrong in my original and modified way to export functions?

Comment: If you change the firs code into 

`return(await this.functionToBeStubbed());`


It will success. Sinon stub the object of `functionstobestested`. But in the fist code, `promiseFunction` call the global function `functionToBeStubbed` which is not already member function of `functionstobestested`. With using `this`, you will ensure that `promiseFunction` call the `functionstobestested`'s `functionToBeStubbed`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I only need to understand how this. changes promiseFunction to functionstobestested's functionToBeStubbed instead of the global :)